# PowerBI DAX measure to sum over most recent values per category

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have a table in PowerBI which holds the inventory levels of different categories at various dates. Example data:

**InventoryTable**

| Category | Date | Inventory |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 31.10.2023 | 15 |
| E | 31.10.2023 | 61 |
| A | 31.12.2023 | 1 |
| B | 31.12.2023 | 13 |
| A | 31.01.2024 | 39 |
| B | 31.01.2024 | 72 |
| B | 29.02.2024 | 38 |
| A | 31.03.2024 | 46 |

More readable, the InventoryTable looks like this

| Category | 31.10.2023 | 31.12.2023 | 31.01.2024 | 29.02.2024 | 31.03.2024 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 15 | 1 | 39 |  | 46 |
| B |  | 13 | 72 | 38 |  |
| E | 61 |  |  |  |  |

A DAX measure "Latest Inventory" should now take the most recent values from the selected time slice (or earlier) per category and sum them up over the categories.

Expected output:

**Latest Inventory**

| Category | 2023 | 2024 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 46 | 46 |
| B | 13 | 38 | 38 |
| E | 61 | 61 | 61 |
| **Total** | **75** | **145** | **145** |

drilled down into month, this should look like

**Latest Inventory**

| Category | October | November | December | **2023 Total** | January | February | March | 2024 Total | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 15 | 15 | 1 | **1** | 39 | 39 | 46 | **46** | **46** |
| B |  |  | 13 | **13** | 72 | 38 | 38 | **38** | **38** |
| E | 61 | 61 | 61 | **61** | 61 | 61 | 61 | **61** | **61** |
| **Total** | **76** | **76** | **75** | **75** | **172** | **138** | **145** | **145** | **145** |

I absolutely cannot get my head around this. Most approaches either fail because different categories have different record dates or the split between the categories is not reflected in the totals. Can it be that hard?

**edit 1:**

Thinking more about it, I assume that I need to bring a DateTable into the model and align my inventory records along the Date column. Similar to what one would do to accumulate values over time - just that in this case, I do not need to sum up over time but only take the most recent value.

I just don't understand how to do that.

**edit 2:**

I might be closer to a solution by now. This is what I have:

```
Latest Inventory = CALCULATE(
    LASTNONBLANKVALUE('InventoryTable'[Date], SUM('InventoryTable'[Inventory])),
    DateTable[Date] <= MAX(DateTable[Date]),
    ALL(DateTable[Date])
)
```

It does calculate the correct values per category. But if I sum up over the categories, the total only has the sum of values that have been recorded at the most current date of ALL categories. If one category has been recorded earlier, it's not contained in the Total.

Already tried to `SUMX` over the `VALUES('InventoryTable'[Category])`, but this messes up the whole thing.

Comment: For A for example, how can we know which value to take if the both rows have 31.10.2023? how can we suppose the order here ? there is a timestamp maybe?

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi, there will always be only one inventory value per category per date. so if one would filter by category and then sort by date, the order should be clear.
Two values for different categories per same date, should be summed up, if not sliced by category.

Answer (score 0):

In combination with a pivot table this should work for your monthly and yearly data

```
MostRecentMonthlyInventory = 
VAR CurrentCategory = SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Category])
VAR CurrentYear = YEAR(MAX('Table'[Date]))
VAR CurrentMonth = MONTH(MAX('Table'[Date]))
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Table'[Inventory]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Table'),
        'Table'[Category] = CurrentCategory &&
        YEAR('Table'[Date]) = CurrentYear &&
        MONTH('Table'[Date]) = CurrentMonth &&
        'Table'[Date] = CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[Date]),
            ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[Category])
        )
    )
)
```

I wrote this code first then changed my mind about the best way to do this. to show totals for 23 and most recent for 24 an have included it because

```
MostRecentInventory2023 = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Table'[Inventory]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Table'),
        'Table'[Date] = CALCULATE(
            MAX('Table'[Date]),
            FILTER(
                ALL('Table'),
                YEAR('Table'[Date]) = 2023 && 
                'Table'[Category] = EARLIER('Table'[Category])
            )
        )
    )
)

MostRecentInventory2024 = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Table'[Inventory]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Table'),
        'Table'[Date] = CALCULATE(
            MAX('Table'[Date]),
            FILTER(
                ALL('Table'),
                YEAR('Table'[Date]) = 2024 && 
                'Table'[Category] = EARLIER('Table'[Category])
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Hm, I tried both measures, none of them really solves my problem.

MostRecentMonthlyInventory only gives a value in the specific month where the last inventory was recorded.
MostRecentInventory2023 always returns 61.